# Change relative paths in minified CSS with cssmin

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin, clean-css

Seems this is not solved besides being a recurrent question.

This is my folder structure:

```
project/
 |
 |--src/
 |   |--images/
 |   +--styles/
 |        +--style.css
 | 
 +--build/
     |--images/
     +--style.min.css
```

Note how `src/styles/style.css` will reference `url(../images/image.png)` while the minified version `build/style.min.css` should reference `url(images/image.png)`

What combination of options for cssmin or clean-css can achieve this?

My current configuration:

```
cssmin: {
  target: {
    files: {
      'build/style.min.css': 'src/styles/style.css'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend simplify life and keep same relative folder structure for css/images. So I would simply use `build/styles/style.min.css`.

Comment: You need to set your paths according to the final destination folder, assume your files was in that folders.